# Unable to send messages to multiple recipients through Sinch in Android App

Tags: android, sinch

I have tried sending a Sinch message in my Android app and it works perfectly when sending to a single recipient

## MyClass

```
String userId= "abc";
CustomReplyMessageBuild customMessage = new CustomReplyMessageBuild();
customMessage.setRecepientIDs(userId);
Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
m1.put(“param1", "YES");
m1.put(“param2”, 123);
m1.put(“param3", time);
customMessage.setHeaders(m1);
messageService.sendMessage(customMessage);
```

## MyBean

```
private List<String> RecepientIds = new ArrayList<String>();
private Map map;
private void setHeaders(Map map) {
this.map = map;}
private void setRecepientIDs(String id) {
        this.RecepientIds.add(id);
    }
```

## MyService

```
private MessageClient messageClient = client.getMessageClient();
public void sendMessage(MyClass.CustomReplyMessageBuild conf_message){`
if(messageClient != null){
    WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(conf_message);
    messageClient.send(message);
   }
}
```

But when i try passing a list of recipient ids (for a broadcast sort of feature) , i am unable to receive the message at the other end .

## MyBroadcastClass

```
List<String> broadcastIdList;
String recepId = "a,b,c";
CustomReplyMessageBuild customMessage = new CustomReplyMessageBuild();
broadcastIdList = Arrays.asList(recepId.split(","));
customMessage.setRecepientIdList(broadcastIdList);
Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
m1.put(“param1", "YES");
m1.put(“param2”, 123);
m1.put(“param3", time);
customMessage.setHeaders(m1);
messageService.sendMessage(customMessage);
```

## MyBroadcastBean

```
private List<String> RecepientIds = new ArrayList<String>();
private Map map;
private void setHeaders(Map map) {
this.map = map;}
private void setRecepientIdList(List<String> idList) {
this.RecepientIds.addAll(idList);
}
```

Please let me know if you spot an error or can post a sample snippet or link to solve this problem. 
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

To send messages to multiple recipients try the following constructor:

```
// Create a WritableMessage and send to multiple recipients

    WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(
        {"recipient user id 1", "recipient user id 2"},
        "Hello recipients! How are you?");  

// Send it

     messageClient.send(message);
```